# How to estimate the input vector norm of inner product with small space cost?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, parameter-estimation

Given a public vector $A$=$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n_q$ and a unknown input vector $B$=$(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$, which could be sampled from either $\mathbb{Z}^n_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$, and their inner product $A \cdot B$=$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\cdot b_i \bmod q$, what's the most efficient way to determine whether $B$ is sampled from $\mathbb{Z}^n_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ in terms of space cost? To put it another way, how could one determine the infinity norm of $B$ using the least space? A straightforward way would be to simply publish $B$ itself, however, that would obviously take a linear space cost. Does there exist an algorithm that estimates the norm of $B$ correctly with non-negligible probability using sublinear space?

Comment: Interesting question: what problem or range of problems inspired you in asking it?

Comment: Oh, thanks for your interest. It's related to the hardness of the knapsack problem. If B has a small norm, then it is hard to calculate B. I came across this problem when I am doing research in Cryptography, and it seems to have quite a strong implication in Crypto. Do you think there is a solution to this problem?

Comment: Currently I don't know if there can be a solution to your precise problem: however, I find your question interesting since it shows one of the mathematical aspects of cryptography I was not aware of.